# Rails 3 vanity URLs with url_for integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I would like vanity URLs for the #show action on one of my controllers. I've setup this route:

```
match "/:username" => "users#show", as: :show_user
```

I would really like to be able to use this vanity URL with the standard way to link to a user show, like so:

```
link_to("foo", user)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jesse Wolgamott has the right idea but a couple notes...

this should go at the bottom of routes.rb so that it doesn't clobber any other routes

```
resources :users, :path => '/'
```

UsersController#show

```
@user = User.where(:username => params[:id])
```

Answer (score 0):

One (slightly verbose) way to do this with your current route setup is

`link_to "foo", show_user_path(user)`

Alternatively,

- You could name your route 'user instead' of 'show_user'. And then override the provided `show_user_url(user)` helper to use user.username instead of user.id
- Under the covers `link_to` calls [`polymorphic_url`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes/polymorphic_url), which calls [`build_named_route_call`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes/build_named_route_call) you could monkey-path build_named_route to call your custom route instead of the regular `user_url`.

Unfortunately, there is no public api/configuration to make this happen cleanly.

Comment: Yeah, I've got it setup now like so:

    link_to "foo", show_user_path(user.username)

And that works. It would just be ideal to have it work like the regular CRUD link_to

Comment: Do you also have a `resources` mapped for the user. It may just be that the regular `link_to` is picking the first path available.

Comment: Tried removing resources and renaming it to 'user', now when i run link_to("foo", user) it returns /id instead of /username.

Answer (score 0):

**routes.rb**

```
resources :users, :path => '/'
```

**user.rb**

```
def to_param
  username.parameterize
end
```

If there is a username of Bob, then `<%= link_to user.username, user%>` will create

```
<a href="/bob">Bob</a>
```